# Is it possible to call a method from a DLL on a PHP webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, dll

Me and a friend are working on a C# windows application. He's in charge of designing the application, while I am in charge of the API.

I have created a DLL which will be used by the application for a majority of MySQL queries. I am also making a website to go along with the application and would like to make a smaller version of the app on the server (which is Linux, I should add) and have it run on the webpage.

So I am wondering if there is a way to call the methods from my DLL in a PHP page, or if I am better off just querying the database with PHP script or something of that nature.

Comment: Yes, you can call a COM DLL from PHP. Also, there are lots of potential dupes of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dll+%5Bphp%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a Windows DLL on a Linux server.  Maybe there's some way to hack stuff in with Wine... I'm not sure, but it's undoubtedly more hassle than it is worth.

You can use COM DLLs and .NET assemblies from within PHP.  See the documentation:  http://php.net/manual/en/book.com.php

If all you are doing is making MySQL queries, you are most certainly better off using PDO or MySQLi.  This will simplify things greatly.

Comment: Alright thank you. I didn't think it would be possible to do it straight forward on linux. I was hoping there would be a really easy way to get around it, but I guess I'm going to be learning some PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having the DLL (I'd assume its a managed assembly) expose out REST or SOAP web services and consume those services via PHP.